# Filtering the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
# Load the dataset
dataset_path = "G:\\assignment\\adult.data.csv"
column_names = ["age", "workclass", "education", "occupation", "race", "sex", "salary"]
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names)

# Background knowledge about Mark
mark_info = {
"age":30,
"workclass": "Private",
"education": "Bachelors",
"occupation": "Adm-clerical",
"race": "White",
"sex": "Male",
"salary": "<=50K"
}

# Convert background knowledge values to strings
for key in mark_info:
 mark_info[key] = str(mark_info[key]).strip()
# Filter the dataset based on the background knowledge
matching_rows = df[
(df["age"] == mark_info["age"]) &
(df["workclass"].str.strip() == mark_info["workclass"]) &
(df["education"].str.strip() == mark_info["education"]) &
(df["occupation"].str.strip() == mark_info["occupation"]) &
(df["race"].str.strip() == mark_info["race"]) &
(df["sex"].str.strip() == mark_info["sex"]) &
(df["salary"].str.strip() == mark_info["salary"])
]

# Print the matching rows
print(matching_rows)
```

Filter not working and output is empty dataset. I have tried to reduce the filter values but not able ti filter with any single attribute

Comment: post a testable input and the expected result

Comment: age,workclass,fnlwgt,education,education-num,marital-status,occupation,house-serv,race,sex,capital-gain,capital-loss,hours-per-week,native-country,salary
39, State-gov,77516, Bachelors,13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male,2174,0,40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc,83311, Bachelors,13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male,0,0,13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private,215646, HS-grad,9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male,0,0,40, United-States, <=50K

Comment: expected output will match the filter. I have tried to filter with a single value filter but the same filter not working

Answer (score 0):

You should read csv data like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, usecols=column_names)
```

If you read data with names parameter, columns also will be indexes. So you can not filter properly because no matching data are exist. You can examine this

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, usecols=column_names)
display(df.head())

df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names)
display(df.head())
```

Comment: matching_rows = df[
    (df["sex"].str.strip() == "Male")
    ]
I have tried with a single filter but the same output empyty dataset

Comment: you need to use '' usecols'' instead of names when reading your csv df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, usecols=column_names)

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy dataset from the column names you provided and was able to filter correctly using your command `df[(df["sex"].str.strip() == "Male")]`

Can you check what does this statement return for you: `df["sex"].str.strip() == "Male"`? I am guessing it is all `False` since you are getting empty rows. After confirming that, check the dtypes of your dataset to confirm nothing funky is happening with values while reading. Also, try to pick one row, and fix it for that. I am guessing if it is fixed for one entry, it will be fixed for all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).